# Is there any possibility to play video in RecyclerView like a header?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-video-player

I've tried to use `VideoView` but `OnErrorListener`, `OnPreparedListener` never called. Reason might be that `SurfaceView` isn't supported in scrollable views.

I'm trying to implement it with `TextureView` but `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` never calls. `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` added into manifest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620131/trouble-getting-video-to-play-on-recyclerview

This may be helpful for you...

Comment: Thanks. But i've saw this post and tried, no expected result

Comment: Additional info: For landscape mode I have VideoView outside of recyclerview and it work perfect (inside VideoView.java setVideoPath is called). But when VideoView inside RecyclerView it doesn't call setVideoPath. Detected by debuging. What the reason could it be?

Comment: Hi @МихаилТаужнянский  I am getting the same problem now... Did U get any solution !!!? Please share me ... If U have ...

Comment: I managed it in a way that is appropriate to specific task requirements. At the end I got layout that contains videoview at the top and recycleview under.

Comment: Could u please post your xml layout

Comment: layout contains only RecycleView inside.
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: the whole logic is in code

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397058/2042341 This may be helpful for you.